# add images in a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developping and android quizz app and i have two problems. First i cannot update the questions and second i want to store images in the database with the questions.Severals persons reply to my request but when i try to do what they say i have some errors. for example when i have images in the drawable folder and what lines would i put in the code below to have my images appear with my questions? Sorry but i'm new on Android Thanks

```
package com.example.toureamidou.piste;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by TOURE Amidou on 24/02/2016.
*/
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Question";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta";
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb";
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc";
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                    + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                    +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
    }    
        private void addQuestions() {
            Questions q1=new Questions("FFFFF","Tata", "Titi", "Toto", "Tata");
            this.addQuestion(q1);
            Questions q2=new Questions("Quel est le plus grand pays au monde", "Suisse", "Italie", "Chine", "Chine");
            this.addQuestion(q2);
            Questions q3=new Questions("Comment s'appele le président francais","Obama", "Hollande","Gorbatchev", "Hollande" );
            this.addQuestion(q3);
            Questions q4=new Questions("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", "ali", "dede", "home","dede");
            this.addQuestion(q4);
            Questions q5=new Questions("Quel est l'homme le plus riche au monde","Gates","Trump","Carlos Slim","Trump");
            this.addQuestion(q5);
        }

    private void addQuestion(Questions quest) {
        SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("addQuestions", quest.toString());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public List<Questions> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Questions> quesList = new ArrayList<Questions>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Questions quest = new Questions();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return quesList;
    }
    public int updateQuestions (Questions questions){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("questions",questions.getQUESTION());
        contentValues.put("answer",questions.getANSWER());
        contentValues.put("opta",questions.getOPTA());
        contentValues.put("optb",questions.getOPTB());
        contentValues.put("optc", questions.getOPTC());
        int i = db.update(TABLE_QUEST, contentValues, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(questions.getID())});
        db.close();
        return i;    
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have some errors" ... which ones?

Comment: For example i want to insert the image doing this

Comment: public final static byte [] image and after put it in the public void addQuestions

Comment: that's part of a method signature, not an error.

Comment: regardless of how many times you ask the same question, you will need to be in a Transaction in order for the records you insert, update, or delete to remain in the sqlite table once your function ends. good luck, though

Comment: Okok can you explain how i can put the images in database and call them with my questions.I have also defined an ImageView with an id

Answer (score 1):

You can not put images into a SQLDatase (well you can add it as blob, but that's not the right thing to do in android). You should save the image's path or id to the database instead of the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can **convert the image to BASE64(basically a string) then store that string in database**. When you want to show image retrieve that string convert to image